# How do I update the Original document post accept changes for a Word Document stored on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word

Note this is a quasi Word/SharePoint question.  I will also post in Word

**Situation**

1. I have MS Word Documents with Tracking Off (MS Word setting) and
   Major Versions On (SharePoint Setting)

   The MS Word Document is Opened and I click on the Review Tab and
   then Compare.  I then select to Compare Specific versions.  In my
   example I have chosen to compare version 6 with version 1.

   Word opens an additional 3 documents at this point (version 1 and
   version 6 and a document called Compare1)

   Within the Comapre1 document I see all the differences between
   documents

   Within the Compare1 document I select within the Review Tab to
   Accept All Changes

**Problem**
The problem is I want all the changes to be reflected in the ORIGINAL document I opened from within MS SharePoint.  However, it appears the changes are only reflected in the Compare1 document
In addition if I do a  save as with the Compare1 document it will attempt to save the document locally not SharePoint

**Question**
Very frustrating - Word does a great job of showing me the differences and then accepting or rejecting the changes, but no way to overwrite the original document I opened from within SharePoint.  I am sure I must be overlooking something - surely I can update the original without having to save off Compare1 locally and then loading Compare1 to SharePoint and then renaming the the Compare1 document to the Original document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope restoring the Compare-1 as current version would solve your concern...